# What is the fix to Synchronous ResponseHandler error in Android?

Tags: java, android, json

I'm writing an Android application that, in part, sends put requests to update an API via `PUT`.

A set of objects looks like this:

```
{
            "id": "b04caf39-eefd-4221-a6a9-66dd3e80d6a3",
            "room": "338",
            "request": "Send 5 towels to room 338",
            "time": 1501567055,
            "done": false
        },
```

I'm receiving this error in my log cat:

```
07-31 22:57:57.683 3597-3597/com.example.duncan.recyclerviewproject E/params: https://summerproject17.herokuapp.com/api/request/b04caf39-eefd-4221-a6a9-66dd3e80d6a3
                                                                              id: b04caf39-eefd-4221-a6a9-66dd3e80d6a3
                                                                              Time: 1501567055
                                                                              Request: Send 5 towels to room 338
                                                                              Room: 338
07-31 22:57:57.686 3597-3597/com.example.duncan.recyclerviewproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: com.example.duncan.recyclerviewproject, PID: 3597
                                                                                      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Synchronous ResponseHandler used in AsyncHttpClient. You should create your response handler in a looper thread or use SyncHttpClient instead.
                                                                                          at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.sendRequest(AsyncHttpClient.java:1493)
                                                                                          at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.put(AsyncHttpClient.java:1267)
                                                                                          at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.put(AsyncHttpClient.java:1249)
                                                                                          at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.put(AsyncHttpClient.java:1236)
                                                                                          at com.example.duncan.recyclerviewproject.MainAdapter.putLoopjRequest(MainAdapter.java:213)
                                                                                          at com.example.duncan.recyclerviewproject.MainAdapter.access$000(MainAdapter.java:38)
                                                                                          at com.example.duncan.recyclerviewproject.MainAdapter$1.onClick(MainAdapter.java:117)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I suspect this snippet of my adapter is the culprit:

```
    @Override
    public boolean getUseSynchronousMode() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUseSynchronousMode(boolean useSynchronousMode) {

    }
```

Full adapter can be seen here:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;
import com.loopj.android.http.ResponseHandlerInterface;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpResponse;


public class MainAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    private String PUT_URL="https://summerproject17.herokuapp.com/api/request/";

    Context context;
    ArrayList<ListItem> arraylist=new ArrayList<>();

    public MainAdapter(Context context,
                       ArrayList<ListItem>arrayList){
        this.context=context;
        this.arraylist=arrayList;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arraylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return arraylist.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        Button   mark_btn;
        public TextView textViewRoom;
        public TextView textViewRequest;
        public TextView textViewTime;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {
        View convertView=row;
       final ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null) {

            holder=new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);

            holder.mark_btn= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            holder.textViewRoom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRoom);
            holder.textViewRequest = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRequest);
            holder.textViewTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            FontChangerCrawler fontChanger = new FontChangerCrawler(context.getAssets(), "fonts/elegantluxpro-mager.ttf");
            fontChanger.replaceFonts((ViewGroup)convertView);

        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

        /*convert UnixTime to Time  youy can get minutes ,hours and seconds too*/

        /*Date time=new java.util.Date((long)Long.parseLong(arraylist.get(position).getTime())*1000);

        time.getSeconds();

        time.getMinutes();

        time.getHours();*/

        final ListItem listItem= (ListItem) getItem(position);

        holder.textViewRoom.setText("Room: "+listItem.getRoom());
        holder.textViewRequest.setText(listItem.getRequest());
        holder.textViewTime.setText("Time: "+listItem.getTime());

        holder.mark_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                putLoopjRequest(listItem.getId(),listItem.getRoom(),listItem.getRequest(), listItem.getTime());
                Toast.makeText(context, "Marked complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private void putRequest(final String id, final String room, final String request, final String time)
    {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        JSONObject params=new JSONObject();
        try {
            params.put("id", id);
            params.put("room", room);
            params.put("request",request);
            params.put("time",time);
            params.put("done",true);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonObjectRequest putRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT,PUT_URL + id, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.e("response",response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }

        );
        queue.add(putRequest);
    }
    private  void putVolleyStringRequest(final String id, final String room, final String request, final String time)
    {
        StringRequest putRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, PUT_URL+id,
                new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // response
                        Log.d("Response", response.toString());
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // error
                        Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                    }
                }
        ) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders()
            {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                //or try with this:
                //headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
                return headers;
            }
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("id", id);
                params.put("room", room);
                params.put("request",request);
                params.put("time",time);
                params.put("done",String.valueOf("true"));
                return params;
            }
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json";
            }
        };

        RequestQueue queue=Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        queue.add(putRequest);
    }

    private void putLoopjRequest(final String id, final String room, final String request, final String time)
    {
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("id", id);
        params.put("room", room);
        params.put("request",request);
        params.put("time",Integer.parseInt(time));
        params.put("done",true);
        Log.e("params",PUT_URL+id+"\nid: "+id+"\nTime: "+time+"\nRequest: "+request+"\nRoom: "+room);
        client.put(PUT_URL+id, params, new ResponseHandlerInterface() {
            @Override
            public void sendResponseMessage(HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                Log.e("response",response.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void sendStartMessage() {

            }

            @Override
            public void sendFinishMessage() {

            }

            @Override
            public void sendProgressMessage(long bytesWritten, long bytesTotal) {

            }

            @Override
            public void sendCancelMessage() {

            }

            @Override
            public void sendSuccessMessage(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                Log.e("response","Code is"+statusCode+"\nResponse is: "+responseBody+"");

            }

            @Override
            public void sendFailureMessage(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                Log.e("response","error"+statusCode+"\nResponse is: "+responseBody+"");
            }

            @Override
            public void sendRetryMessage(int retryNo) {
                Log.e("response","Retry"+retryNo);
            }

            @Override
            public URI getRequestURI() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void setRequestURI(URI requestURI) {

            }

            @Override
            public Header[] getRequestHeaders() {
                return new Header[0];
            }

            @Override
            public void setRequestHeaders(Header[] requestHeaders) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean getUseSynchronousMode() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void setUseSynchronousMode(boolean useSynchronousMode) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean getUsePoolThread() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void setUsePoolThread(boolean usePoolThread) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPreProcessResponse(ResponseHandlerInterface instance, HttpResponse response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPostProcessResponse(ResponseHandlerInterface instance, HttpResponse response) {

            }

            @Override
            public Object getTag() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void setTag(Object TAG) {

            }
        });
    }
    }
```

The error is pretty explicit in `Synchronous ResponseHandler used in AsyncHttpClient. You should create your response handler in a looper thread or use SyncHttpClient instead` however, I'm still fairly new to android and haven't found any resources for the best way to implement the fix. What is the best way implement the fix for this error?

Comment: You should post some more of your adapter code, or at least what the super class of the adapter is, so we can interpret your snippet more easily.

Comment: @Elliott I've added the full adapter for context. Initially left it out because I didn't want to make the question too long unless it was necessary.

Comment: I agree that the method `getUseSynchronousMode` is the culprit. Seems you must at the very least return `false` from that method for things to work.

Comment: Have you tried changing it?

Comment: Have you tried using   `AsyncHttpResponseHandler` instead of `ResponseHandlerInterface` ?

Comment: Changing `getUseSynchronousMode` from `true` to `false` resolved the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was resolved thanks to @Elliott's suggestion to change `true` to `false`, updated code can be seen here:

```
@Override
    public boolean getUseSynchronousMode() {
        return false;
    }

@Override
    public void setUseSynchronousMode(boolean useSynchronousMode) {

    }
```